# Tensorflow with Pycharm : inacurrate rise of tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

## Context

After installing Tensorflow-GPU and all its requirements (namely CUDA and cuDNN), I try to run Tensorflow **with GPU support** under Pycharm.

## Problem

When I run a simple program under Pycharm, session.run **rises an exception**.

#### Exception

```
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSessionRef(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

**Important note** : I believe the problem comes from **Pycharm and/or its configuration**, as running the same simple program in a terminal **will throw no exception**.

## Question

**How do I get rid of this exception and have my Pycharm environment work as intended with Tensorflow ?**

## -

## Additional informations

#### My simple test program

```
import tensorflow as tf


def main():
    # define the graph
    a = tf.constant(1.0)
    b = tf.constant(1.0)
    c = tf.constant(4.0)
    d = tf.div(tf.add(a, b), c)

    # execute the graph
    with tf.Session() as session:
        print(session.run(d))  # 0.5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("tensorflow version : " + tf.__version__)
    main()
```

#### Output of the program above when run in a terminal

```
(tf_env) usr@WHATEVER ~/Documents/Repos/tftest/tftest $ python intro.py 
tensorflow version : 1.12.0
2018-12-05 10:56:09.888809: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:964] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-12-05 10:56:09.889285: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1070 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7465
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 7.92GiB freeMemory: 7.52GiB
2018-12-05 10:56:09.889304: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-12-05 10:56:10.126095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-12-05 10:56:10.126135: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2018-12-05 10:56:10.126142: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2018-12-05 10:56:10.126366: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7252 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
0.5
```

#### Pycharm environment variable setup

[image]

#### Installs & hardware

I don't believe the problem comes from my hardware/install but from Pycharm, but here's all you'll need (or not) to know about it

I have Tensorflow installed in a **conda virtual environment** named `tf_env`.

**GPU** : NVIDIA GTX GeForce 1070 (capability of 6.1)

**GPU Drivers** : 384.130

**Linux** : 16.04

**Tensorflow** : 1.12.0

**CUDA Toolkit** : 9.0.176

**cuDNN** : 7.4.1.5

#### Personal relevant research

This quora answer by Gabriel Alhrishy might help : https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-install-TensorFlow-to-use-with-PyCharm

But I've tried to add /usr/local/cuda/bin/ to root content it didn't work and I don't know what he means by cuDNN/bin/ as I'm not aware such directory exists. It's not clear whether I have the same problem or not.

Comment: I've found a solution. The problem actually came from a stupid mixing up of conda environments. I was running another conda environment with a similar name on Pycharm but with a different `Tensorflow` install (from conda, not pip). I'll think on how to write a proper answer for this question (or close it if I can't find a good way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually came from a stupid mixing up of conda environments. I was running another conda environment with a similar name on Pycharm but with a different Tensorflow install (from conda, not pip).

Putting back the correct conda env did the job.